# Fetching database records for a Java entity holding collections

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to fetch oracle database records for an entity using spring data jpa.

It's working fine when there is no collection associated with the entity, but when I add the associated collection to the entity, I am getting SQL exception as Table or view doesn't exist.

Any help highly appreciated!!

Comment: We need some code and some log.
What are the name of the table? Do you see them in the DB?
Show us the entity classes

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statements for your tables; the DML (`INSERT`) statements for some sample data; the Java code you are using; the text of the error message; your expected output for that sample data. Without that, it is very difficult to answer the question as we don't know what you are doing.

Comment: Please provide some code sample that defines the dependencies or relationship between your entities that you are trying to retrieve. What I understand is you have two entities with probably in OneToMany relationship and you want to retrieve the child entities in a collection of some sort at Parent. Please provide some more information to get a sensible guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick responses guys, I could find a solution to the problem. It's resolved now.